# Error upon reassigned function call, why?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with NW.js, in order to create a local websocket-client. I have the principle working, at the moment I'm refactoring my code to be more object oriented.

```
Websockclient.prototype.connect = function() {
    if (!("WebSocket" in window)) {
        alert("WebSocket is NOT supported!");
    } else {
        uri = "ws://" + this.host + ":" + this.port;
        this.ws = new WebSocket(uri);
        this.ws.onopen = function(evt) { this.onOpen(evt); }
    }
};

Websockclient.prototype.log = function(message) {
    if (this.logEn == true) {
        console.log(message);
    }
};

Websockclient.prototype.onOpen = function(evt) {
    this.log("connected");
    this.ws.send("Client says Hi!");
};
```

The connection open's correctly, however something fails in the `Websockclient.prototype.onOpen` function call. The error output is as follows:

> [31910:31910:0530/115015:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(181)] invalid EDID:
>   human unreadable char in name
>   chrome-extension://oimdoepkkglchafiooagncfokloigedg/app/lib/websockclient.js:29
>           this.ws.onopen = function(evt) { this.onOpen(evt); }
>
> TypeError: this.onOpen is not a function
>       at WebSocket.ws.onopen (chrome-> > extension://oimdoepkkglchafiooagncfokloigedg/app/lib/websockclient.js:29:47)

It looks like I have a mistake in the following:

> this.ws.onopen = function(evt) { this.onOpen(evt); }

(NB: this is line nr. 29 in file websockclient.js)

I think this assignment is incorrect, but I'm a bit stuck here. Can somebody can please explain what I'm missing here.

Comment: Why don't you just do `this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen;`? Websockclient.prototype.onOpen receives exactly 1 argument which is even called the same and thus the same you expect for the wrapper function.

Comment: That would not work, because `this` in the onOpen function would not refer to the Websockclient object.

Comment: Like @Azamantes says and add `this.onOpen = this.onOpen.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx to @Pimmol's comment I've solved the problem, The following line:

```
this.ws.onopen = function(evt) { this.onOpen(evt); }
```

Needed to be changed to the following:

```
this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen.bind(this);
```

For more info, see the following documentation:

["The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)